# sendmail running slow on centos

Tags: centos, sendmail, performance

So I am trying to send emails out of one of my boxes running centos, and I have sendmail installed and turned on, but it'll take literally minutes for an email to send. Aren't emails supposed to be almost instant?

Here is my /etc/sysconfig/sendmail file, if it helps any:

```
DAEMON=no
QUEUE=1m
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

I had to change:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
50.56.91.91     nartuomeetsbleach
```

in /etc/hosts to this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost localhost.localdomain
50.56.91.91     nartuomeetsbleach.com
```

It was giving me this error in /var/log/maillog:

```
Feb 20 11:55:16 narutomeetsbleach sendmail[18283]: My unqualified host name (narutomeetsbleach) unknown; sleeping for retry
```

It would sleep because it couldn't resolve the host name "narutomeetsbleach", and would send it later. Just in case you ever run into an issue similar to this!